# MariaDB 10.3.22 innodb_status_output keeps turning on

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

MariaDB 10.3.22 innodb_status_output keeps turning on automatically

Per MySQL docs, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html,
"InnoDB temporarily enables standard InnoDB Monitor output under the following conditions:
1.A long semaphore wait
2.InnoDB cannot find free blocks in the buffer pool
3.Over 67% of the buffer pool is occupied by lock heaps or the adaptive hash index "

MariaDB docs don't mention "InnoDB temporarily enables standard InnoDB Monitor", https://mariadb.com/kb/en/xtradb-innodb-monitors/

Running the commands below does turn off the monitors, but they come back on, probably due to the conditions mentioned above:
SET GLOBAL innodb_status_output=OFF;
SET GLOBAL innodb_status_output_locks=OFF;

I'd like to prevent MariaDB from temporarily turning on InnoDB Monitor. I understand we could fix our db to prevent the conditions above, but we'd like to not have InnoDB Monitor turned on automatically. -Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find an exact solution. I had to turn off all logging to stop the output of "standard InnoDB Monitor". I could not find a way to output error logging without MariaDB automatically turning on "standard InnoDB Monitor output". Note that "standard InnoDB Monitor" outputs millions of lines per day for a medium active db. I'm still interested if anyone should find a solution, thanks -K